# How to test if mod_cache works

Tags: apache2

**Some information:**

```
"Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=300"
```

This tells mod_cache to cache the page for 300 seconds (max-age) - unfortunately mod_cache doesn't know the s-maxage option (see http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL), that's why we must use the max-age option (which also tells your browser to cache).

If mod_cache knew the s-maxage option, we could use

```
"Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=0, s-maxage=300"
```

which would tell mod_cache, but not the browser, to cache the page.

**The question:**
How do I know if mod_cache is actually memory caching anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With firebug, you can disable the entire cache, so every css, js, image, video ...etc, it will  request to the web server.

So if this mod_cache is working, activate the firebug cache and the files that have that header, only will be requested to the web server every s-maxage time

Comment: as stated in my question... mod_cache does not recognise the s-maxage header info

Comment: you can use the set Expires to, like:  set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2013 20:00:00 GMT"  http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#EXPIRES

Comment: it worked using maxage (not the s- one) and by disabling browser cache to view some good http-headers as proof it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

200 responses will contain an Age header. At least it does on Apache 2.2. I did not see the header on 304 responses.